# Oracle PLSQL - How to insert pipeseparated string values into a table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Requirement is like:

I have a string with |(Pipe) separated. I need pull each string value and insert into a table.

eg: String is like A,B,C,D,E,F,L,R,X,Z

```
Table has all the columns from A to Z
```

If the given string has A value, the column should be inserted with 'Yes' else 'No'. Like this if string has value that corresponding column in the table should become 'Yes' else as 'No'.

I wrote a procedure where it is inserting in different rows.

---

```
DECLARE 
LV_VUSR VARCHAR2(1000);
BEGIN
FOR J IN (SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE(MS_APPS_UTILITIES.SPLIT_STRING('A,B,D',','))) 
LOOP
  LV_VUSR := J.COLUMN_VALUE;

     INSert into dummy_v 
     values ('1', decode(J.column_value,'A','Y','N'),decode(J.column_value,'B','Y','N'),decode(J.column_value,'C','Y','N'),decode(J.column_value,'D','Y','N'));

END LOOP;
END;
```

I have written this block where multiple rows are getting inserted for the same id.  Can any one help on this?

Comment: Showing your procedure might help. And your table structure, and expected result. (You also said the steing it pipe-separated but your example has commas).

Comment: I have written an ananymous block. As i already mentioned table will be having 60 columns. String values are nothing but column names. String comes from an xml file. If string has values with corresponding column name then that column should be inserted as 'Yes' else as 'No'.

Comment: What is the structure of the table you are inserting into, including all indexes/constraints? Presumably it has a primary key value which is causing the ORA-00001 - is there a value in your XML that corresponds to that key, or are you planning to set it from a sequence (directly or through a trigger), or inferred from the XML node sequence, or something else? Adding a (small) sample XML and the data you expect that to populate in your table would help too.

Answer (score 2):

This might be overly simplified, but if you can rely on the quality of your input data, why not just this:

```
INSERT INTO table_name
WITH data ( id, value ) AS (
  SELECT 1, 'A,B,E' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'B,E' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT d.id,
       CASE WHEN INSTR(d.value,'A') > 0 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END A,
       CASE WHEN INSTR(d.value,'B') > 0 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END B,
       CASE WHEN INSTR(d.value,'C') > 0 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END C,
       CASE WHEN INSTR(d.value,'D') > 0 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END D,
       CASE WHEN INSTR(d.value,'E') > 0 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END E
FROM   data d
```

`REGEXP_INSTR` could be used instead to cover some minor variations in the input data.

Comment: I am getting error mentioned below:  00001. 00000 -  "unique constraint (%s.%s) violated"
*Cause:    An UPDATE or INSERT statement attempted to insert a duplicate key.
           For Trusted Oracle configured in DBMS MAC mode, you may see
           this message if a duplicate entry exists at a different level.
*Action:   Either remove the unique restriction or do not insert the key. Since i have made id as primary key. Table insertion is happening into different rows.

Comment: From the code in your question, it looks like you are trying to insert separate rows into the table.  E.g., if your data for `id` = 1 was 'A,B,C', you'd insert 3 rows: (1, Y, N, N), (1, N, Y, N), and (1, N, N, Y).  If you're going to take an approach that involves splitting the comma-separated data into rows, you need to aggregate them again at the end.  MT0's approach does that perfectly.  My approach does not separate the data into rows, so there is no need for aggregation in my example.

Answer (score 1):

A smaller example with 5 columns (you should be able to scale it up to all 26):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  id INT,
  A CHAR(1),
  B CHAR(1),
  C CHAR(1),
  D CHAR(1),
  E CHAR(1)
);
```

**Query**:

```
INSERT INTO table_name
WITH data ( id, value ) AS (
  SELECT 1, 'A,B,E' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'B,E' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT d.id, 
       CASE WHEN COUNT( CASE WHEN t.COLUMN_VALUE = 'A' THEN 1 END ) > 0
            THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END, 
       CASE WHEN COUNT( CASE WHEN t.COLUMN_VALUE = 'B' THEN 1 END ) > 0
            THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END, 
       CASE WHEN COUNT( CASE WHEN t.COLUMN_VALUE = 'C' THEN 1 END ) > 0
            THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END, 
       CASE WHEN COUNT( CASE WHEN t.COLUMN_VALUE = 'D' THEN 1 END ) > 0
            THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END, 
       CASE WHEN COUNT( CASE WHEN t.COLUMN_VALUE = 'E' THEN 1 END ) > 0
            THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END
FROM   data d,
       TABLE(
        CAST(
          MULTISET(
            SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR( d.value, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL )
            FROM   DUAL
            CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT( d.value, '[^,]+' )
          ) AS SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST
        )
       ) t
GROUP BY d.id;
```

**Output**:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name;

        ID A B C D E
---------- - - - - -
         1 Y Y N N Y 
         2 N Y N N Y
```

Or a solution using a short stored function:

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TYPE stringlist IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(20);
/

CREATE FUNCTION split_String(
  i_str    IN  VARCHAR2,
  i_delim  IN  VARCHAR2 DEFAULT ','
) RETURN stringlist DETERMINISTIC
AS
  p_result       stringlist := stringlist();
  p_start        NUMBER(5) := 1;
  p_end          NUMBER(5);
  c_len CONSTANT NUMBER(5) := LENGTH( i_str );
  c_ld  CONSTANT NUMBER(5) := LENGTH( i_delim );
BEGIN
  IF c_len > 0 THEN
    p_end := INSTR( i_str, i_delim, p_start );
    WHILE p_end > 0 LOOP
      p_result.EXTEND;
      p_result( p_result.COUNT ) := SUBSTR( i_str, p_start, p_end - p_start );
      p_start := p_end + c_ld;
      p_end := INSTR( i_str, i_delim, p_start );
    END LOOP;
    IF p_start <= c_len + 1 THEN
      p_result.EXTEND;
      p_result( p_result.COUNT ) := SUBSTR( i_str, p_start, c_len - p_start + 1 );
    END IF;
  END IF;
  RETURN p_result;
END;
/
```

**Query**:

```
INSERT INTO table_name
WITH data ( id, value ) AS (
  SELECT 1, 'A,B,E' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'B,E' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT id,
       CASE WHEN 'A' MEMBER OF vs THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END,
       CASE WHEN 'B' MEMBER OF vs THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END,
       CASE WHEN 'C' MEMBER OF vs THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END,
       CASE WHEN 'D' MEMBER OF vs THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END,
       CASE WHEN 'E' MEMBER OF vs THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END
FROM  (
  SELECT id,
         split_String( value ) AS vs
  FROM   data
);
```

**Output**:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name;

        ID A B C D E
---------- - - - - -
         1 Y Y N N Y 
         2 N Y N N Y
```

Comment: DECLARE 
LV_VUSR VARCHAR2(1000);
BEGIN
FOR J IN (SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE(MS_APPS_UTILITIES.SPLIT_STRING('A,B,D',','))) 
LOOP
  LV_VUSR := J.COLUMN_VALUE;

     INSert into dummy_v 
     values ('1', decode(J.column_value,'A','Y','N'),decode(J.column_value,'B','Y','N'),decode(J.column_value,'C','Y','N'),decode(J.column_value,'D','Y','N'));

END LOOP;
END;            Multiple rows are getting inserted. Any one can help on this?